# Paste values from 3 cells into one cell with delimiters in excel

Tags: excel

I have the following data where A to C are the columns:

```
     A      B       C
    -5.274  -20.63  9.251
```

where each number is in a different cell.

I want to combine these numbers in the following way and paste them into a new cell (those of column D)

```
-5.274 (-20.63 − 9.251)
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't copy and paste them like that, but you can very easily:

D2: `=A2 & " (" & B2 & " - " & C2 & ")"`

Answer (score 0):

To keep the formatting:

```
=TEXT(A1;"0.00")& "(" & TEXT(B1;"0.00") & " " & TEXT(C1;"0.00") & ")"
```